# Display the contents of a CSV File read by scanner into a JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have a program that allows users to log in to a system, present them with various options for manipulating data that is held in a CSV file. This file is read by Scanner, split and stored in a variable.

I want to display the entire file in a JFrame, I have some code below and would appreciate any guidance at all. The console prints the data as expected but I cannot get it to display on the JFrame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AllLoanObjects implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel allLoanObjLabel = new JLabel("All Loan Objects");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Close");
    ArrayList<String[]> listFile = new ArrayList<>();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    AllLoanObjects() throws IOException {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1200, 1000);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        allLoanObjLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 750, 35);
        allLoanObjLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 25));

        textArea.setEditable(false);
        listFile = new CSVReader().read("mortgageandloan.csv");
        for (String[] row : listFile) {
            textArea.append(row + "\n");
            System.out.println(String.join(",", row));
        }

        exitButton.setBounds(900, 10, 80, 25);
        exitButton.setFocusable(false);
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);

        frame.add(allLoanObjLabel);
        frame.add(textArea);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(exitButton);

        for (String[] row : listFile) {
            System.out.println(String.join(",", row));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == exitButton) {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` bad start. `frame.setVisible(true);` make this the last thing you do

Comment: *" I cannot get it to display on the JFrame"* - move `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of the constructor

Comment: Remove `frame.add(textArea);`, it's already contained within the scrollpane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change this line
`textArea.append(row + "\n");`
to this `textArea.append(String.join(",", row) + "\n");`
because it does not know how to print an array of strings. The String.join combines the Strings in the Array into one string each separated by the first argument (in this case ","). It's the same thing you did to print the lines to the console.